# How to check double *array?

Tags: c, arrays, types

I try to store my data in double *array.

```
double* parse_string(char *string)
...
double *parsed_string = parse_string(str);
```

I want to store numbers like 124.1546 and operators like '+'. The problem is: when this data is in array, I can't detect which one is number and which is operator. 
I have tried isdigit() and isalpha(), but in works only with char *array. 
Should I store data somehow else?

UPD: I try to make Reverse Polish notation. For that I get string with fgets from stdin, then parse this string with this function:

```
double* parse_string(char *string)
{
char result_digits[50][50];
char result_operators[50];
static double result_string[100];

int i = 0;
int digits_cnt = 0;
int digit_string = 0;
int operators_cnt = 0;
while (string[i] != '\n') {
    if (detect_symbol_type(string[i]) == sym_digit || string[i] == '.') {
        result_digits[digit_string][digits_cnt] = string[i];
        digits_cnt++;
    } else {
        if (detect_symbol_type(string[i]) == sym_operator) {
            result_operators[operators_cnt] = string[i];
            result_digits[digit_string][digits_cnt] = '\n';
            operators_cnt++;
            digit_string++;
            digits_cnt = 0;
        }
    }
    i++;
}
result_operators[operators_cnt] = '\n';

double result_numbers[100];
for (int i = 0; i <= digit_string; i++) {
    double result = 0;
    sscanf(result_digits[i], "%lf", &result);
    result_numbers[i] = result;
    printf("Parse result: %lf\n", result);
}

int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= (digit_string + operators_cnt); i++) {
    result_string[i] = result_numbers[k];
    printf("%lf", result_string[i]);
    i++;
    result_string[i] = result_operators[k];
    printf("%c", (char)result_string[i]);
    k++;
}

return result_string;
}
```

So I can receive double array with all numbers and operators or two arrays separately. And I start to think that two arrays in my case is not such a bad idea...

Comment: Double only stores floating point numbers, never characters. Please expand your question a bit with the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: If so, it's horrible for my program. Thanks for comment.

Comment: What are the input data supposed to look like?  Is it always N numbers with N-1 operators between them?

Comment: Almost. It's char *str, looks like 1+4*3+(1-2)

Comment: Why do you want to store a `string` as a `double*` array?

Comment: you could use two arrays, one for the numbers(array of double) and another for the operator(array of char)

Comment: I have just updated question.

Comment: you might want to have a look at K&R chapter 4. unless you are using the same book(everyone should) there is an elegant solution to the reverse polish calc.

Comment: but that method works only with char! I need double too. Something like 124020.12454 - it also must be calculated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a computer:

- Numbers are stored as bits (001110101010101110001)
- Characters/operators are stored as bits (000011101111010101101)

There is no inherent property allowing to distinguish one from another. It is *you* as a programmer who specifies how a given data should be interpreted. If you lose that information, e.g. by storing numbers and characters together at the same location, it cannot be recovered.

What you *can* do however, is to store that information (how the data should be interpreted) explicitly, in a separate bit value. A typical low-level construct is a union and a flag:

```
typedef enum {
    Number,
    Operator,
    SomethingElse,
    ...
} MyDataType;

typedef struct {
    MyDataType type;
    union {
        double number;
        char op;
    };
} MyData;
```

Now, if you have an object of type `MyData`, say `x` you can check what it is by accessing:

```
x.type
```

and when you set the value of it, you need to set the new type and the appriopriate field. For example, assigning a number it would look as:

```
x.type = Number;
x.number = 124.1546
```

If you are into object-oriented programming in C++ this a bit cumbersome mechanic can be hidden with access members.